# HOW TO use Enterprise Architect(EA) to generate the class diagram of a QT project?

Tags: c++, qt, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I always use Enterprise Architect to generate the class diagram of a C++ project from the source files.
Now, I have a QT projecct. Is there any way to generate the class diagram from QT source files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you probably need to run qmake first and include the meta-object sources.

Another possibility (or you might need to do this anyway) is to add the Qt-specific preprocessor macros (`SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` and the QObject-defined ones for instance) to EA. I don't have an installation handy at the moment so I'm not able to tell you exactly how it is done.

Comment: +1: @stevenYANG, Please don't forget to share your findings related to the Qt-specific preprocessor macros to EA. Thank you.